# One IP Address and Wildcard Certificate for multiple Virtual Hosts (Windows, Apache 2.4.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2e)

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, virtualhost

I have searched and searched but I cannot find a solution to my issue, so apologies if this sounds familiar, but I am at a loss.

I have:

- Windows environment
- Apache 2.4.2
- OpenSSL 1.0.2e
- one IP address (development box: 127.0.0.1)
- multiple virtual hosts (www.site.co.uk, sub.site.co.uk, etc. )
- Genuine domain validated wildcard certificate from Comodo

I need to use the wildcard certificate for all of my virtual hosts.

All the sites work fine when using the standard http over port 80.

When I enable httpd-ssl.conf, I start to get into trouble.

I have seen and tried several examples of http-ssl.conf configurations but all result in intermittent connection failures, i.e. Firefox: "*Secure Connection Failed*", IE11: "*This page cannot be displayed*". **However**, if I refresh the page (in each browser) the page displays and I can see that the certificate is valid.

From what I've read, it points to incorrect configuration of the http-ssl.conf, but I've tried the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator (https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), many stackoverflow answers, but still no joy.

This is my current httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
Listen  443 https

SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLSessionCache     "shmcb:C:/Apache2.4/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLProtocol         All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName  www.site.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.site.co.uk
    DocumentRoot    C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\htdocs\www.site.co.uk

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\site_wildcard.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\site_wildcard.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\conf\extra\ssl\site_wildcard.ca-bundle"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName  sub.site.co.uk
    ServerAlias sub.site.co.uk
    DocumentRoot    C:\WebServer\Apache2.4\htdocs\sub.site.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: You should also provide real information, like the real URL of the server; and not fake information. ***`openssl s_client -connect www.site.co.uk:443 -tls1 -servername www.site.co.uk`*** executes fine.

Comment: What does https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ says about your server ?

Comment: @Tom The site is still in development, so testing on a sandbox server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, my original comment did not solve the problem.

The certificate was configured correctly.

When running tests, on websites like ssllabs.com, the protocol and handshake results would randomly differ, even though no configuration change had taken place.

Testing/Verfiying with OpenSSL, sporadically produced the correct result, but the majority of time resulted in:

> ssl handshake failed

It turns out the culprit was that I had this in my httpd.conf file:

```
AcceptFilter https none
```

After commenting it out, it solved the problem:

```
#AcceptFilter https none
```